# Pydev+Eclipse (with SL4A) to write full android apps?

Tags: android, python, eclipse, pydev, sl4a

I am trying to develop a few android applications and all that I have managed to do was write scripts on Eclipse with PyDev and transfer them to my Android phone with SL4A. These work run fine and work great but I want a full application (like one you could click from 'desktop'). I cannot find any information in how to do that. Can anybody throw a bone?

Valentine

Comment: you may want to look into kivy ... Im not too sure about android developement personally, but I know that kivy is used widely to get python on android

Comment: from what I understand Kivy is the same thing as SL4A: it just sets up a connection to Android so you can pass your scripts and test them quickly. I actually really hope i'm wrong cause I'm stuck...

Comment: do you get an apk file? Im pretty sure you can make apk files with kivy that you can then install ... if they are just running on top of SL4A then maybe this will help  http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AIDE+sl4a to create apk files, but them will require Python library 
[how-to-create-an-android-app-and-apk-on-android-with-python](http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2012/07/31/how-to-create-an-android-app-and-apk-on-android-with-python/)